# JNI, Java to C++ in Eclipse: undefined reference to '_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12'

Tags: c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, undefined

I'm a beginner to c++ and JNI and I want to call a Java methode from my C++ program.
When compiling (with Eclipse) I get the following error:

> undefined reference to '_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12'

I searched for this problem and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860021/undefined-reference-to-jni-createjavavm-linux)

There the answer was, if I get that right, including the jvm library to the compiling command. Since I'm not compiling by hand I'm not sure how I can make Eclipse do this. Could somebody explain that step by step for a complete beginner?

Here is the code, in case the compiling command won't change anything and the code has some errors.
In this part the error is displayed when calling JNI_CreateJavaVM:

```cpp
JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) {

JNIEnv *env;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption options;

/*
 * The following is a little messy, but options.optionString wants a char* not a string
 * So I convert the String-path to a char-array
 */
string stringPath = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\Chris\\workspacejava\\PP\\src\\Tests"; //Path to the java source code

int sLen = stringPath.length();

char javaPath [sLen + 1];
int i = 0;
for(; i < sLen; i++)
{

    javaPath[i] = stringPath[i];
}
javaPath[i] = '\0';

options.optionString = javaPath;
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = &options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;


int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args); //This call results in the error: undefined reference to '_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12'
if(ret < 0)
    printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");     
return env;}
```

And here I call this function:

```cpp
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM * jvm;
    env = create_vm(&jvm);
    if (env == NULL)
        return 1;
    ...
    int n = jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```

Further Informations: (I don't know if they help)
I use Windows 7. Both Eclipse and JDK are 64Bit. I'm using MinGW GCC to compile my code.

I'm glad for every piece of advice

Comment: Eclipse CDT supports various tool chains (e.g. MinGW GCC, MSVC, Cygwin GCC). Which one are you using in this project?

Comment: I'm using MinGW GCC right now. But I could change that easily if that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you need to add the `jvm` library to your build.

1. Open the project properties dialog.
2. Select C++ Builder > Settings on the left.
3. Select the Tool Setting tab.
4. Select MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries.
5. Add `jvm` in the Libraries section.
6. Add the path to your JDK `lib` folder in the Libraries Search Path section.

I have a JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to a JRE subfolder of a JDK so I enter the search path like this: `"${env_var:JAVA_HOME}/../lib"`, with quotes because the environment variable expands to a path with spaces in it.

Now, you might have 32-bit and/or 64-bit JDKs installed. Be sure to use files from the same bit-ness as your compiler output. That includes running your exe with the right jvm.dll first on the [DLL search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). On 64-bit Windows, the 32-bit JDK is usually installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\Java....

The `@12` says that your compiler is producing 32-bit code (the arguments to JNI_CreateJavaVM are 3 pointers of 4-bytes each) so the linker needs the 32-bit version of jvm.lib rather than the 64-bit version.

---

BTW—Your `java.class.path` looks a suspicious for two reasons:

1. `Tests` looks like the name of a class. The class path should be a ;-separated list of paths to the root folder of packages. If `Tests` is a class in the default package, just lop off `Tests` from your class path.
2. Eclipse usually sets up Java projects with separate source and binary folders. The paths in the class path are where `java` should search for `.class` files. If your project is configured to compile `.java` files from the `src` folder to `.class` files in the `bin` folder, then replace `src` with `bin` in your class path.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But I still get different errors for the different things I tried:   1. I tried including the absolute path of the lib in the Librarie Search Path ("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\lib"). I got the same error as before. But I saw that the jvm.dll file isn't in the lib folder.

Comment: 2. I included the absolute path of the jvm.dll file ("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\server"). This resulted in the error: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\server/jvm.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized. I also tried it with "/" instead of "\" in the path, but I got the same error.      3. I tried it with the JAVA_HOME path ("${env_var:JAVA_HOME}/bin/client") then I get the error: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ljvm. I am not sure how to continue now.

Comment: Note: I found 3 different JDK-folders that all ahve a jvm.dll file ("Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21", "Program Files\Java\jre7", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7") Does it make a difference which one of them I try to include?

Comment: jvm.dll isn't involved until runtime. The linker needs to know paths for .lib files and be told to look in jvm.lib for functions to be linked.

Comment: When I give Eclipse the path to the jvm.lib file ("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\lib") I get the same error I started with : C:\Users\Chris\workspacec++\JavaWrap\Debug/../CTest.cpp:65: undefined reference to `_imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12. What did I do wrong? Is it possible that I missed out something I should have done earlier? Something like including the jvm.lib-Path to the Path environment variable or something similar (I tried this one already).  I'm sorry if I tax your patience with stupid errors but I have really no idea how to continue...

Comment: @user2479025 I am having the same problem; switching from dll to library still produces the same error (undefined reference). How did you get it to finally work?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as well. Do you remember what you did @user2479025 ?