# Unable to access library

Tags: c

I want to use libpfm4 library for Perf_Event 
but compiling program which have library function
throws following error.

```
   /tmp/ccYD603t.o: In function `main':
    encod.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `pfm_initialize'
    encod.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `pfm_strerror'
    encod.c:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `pfm_get_perf_event_encoding'
    encod.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `pfm_strerror'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

please can any one tell me how configure library in system to resolve this error.

Comment: That is a linker failure. Libraries at end (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923495/undefined-reference-shm-open-already-add-lrt-flag-here).

Comment: Show how you're compiling.

Comment: Please provide all relevant information to reproduce your problem. Right now, we don't know a) what code you compile and b) how you invoke the compiler. Both pieces of information are needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, you're looking at a linker error. Because this is a common error we have a reference question for this:

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

To tell you more about exactly what you're doing wrong we'll need to see how you're compiling. Briefly, you're likely `#include`ing library headers but not linking the library. The compiler is telling the linker that the compiled code will need entities declared in the library headers but then the linker chokes because it doesn't know the definitions of those entities.