# undefined reference to `shm_open' using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, librt

I am using CMake under Ubuntu 14.04 to configure my project.
I need to use a 3rd party library (say stuff.so).
In the CMakeLists.txt, I use TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES to link the stuff library.
However, I got an error:

> DIR_TO_LIB/stuff.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `shm_open'

I tried to put these flag in the CMakeLists.txt but it didn't work:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lrt")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lrt")
```

A post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923495/undefined-reference-shm-open-already-add-lrt-flag-here)) saying that -lrt should be put as the last argument of g++. In my case where CMake is used, how shall I do this?

**UPDATE**:
I added

```
SET (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)
```

and I found that -lrt is not the last (even though I put it at the end of the target link). Please see this [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/36ee0a10c82eff5aa9e4) for compile output.

As you can see from the compile output, there are some linking flags for the opencv.
I don't understand how could this happen as I link the OpenCV library first in the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES. How does CMake handle these linking order?

Please also see my [CMakeLists.txt](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/370446fbeac1f0aae87d).

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `rt` in `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` as a last one, for example:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_app ${Boost_LIBRARIES} rt)
```

You can verify position of `rt` by enabling verbose build output:

```
SET (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution but it didn't work. Please see my update for the compile output and my CMakeLists. Thanks very much

Comment: hmm some of OpenCV libs are linked twice. Try adding `ADD_DEPENDENCIES(vidcapture ${OpenCV_LIBS} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Multimedia aja ajastuff rt)` between `ADD_EXECUTABLE` and `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`

Comment: Yes the issue is that the opencv was link twice. When I removed opencv from the `target_link_libraryies` it could pass the compile. I also tried the `ADD_DEPENDENCIES` but the same error.

Answer (score 1):

First, the answer is: Append `-lrt` to **the end** of your macro `target_link_libraries` for your target `my_app`, i.e.,

```
target_link_libraries(my_app ${Boost_LIBRARIES} -lrt)
```

That achieves the same effect in solving the missing library to be linked against by using e.g. gcc compiler:

```bash
gcc my_app.c -o my_app -lrt
```

The reason behind, as you may have already figured out, is the missing required ("realtime") library. For that, you can check by typing in the command

```bash
man shm_open
```

and then finding the key snippet explaining the reason of adding `-lrt`, i.e.,
"These functions are provided in glibc 2.2 and  later.   Programs  using these  functions  must  specify  the  -lrt  flag to cc in order to link against the required ("realtime") library."