# CMake link opencv twice mess up compiler command order

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, g++

Environment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

I use `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )` to find the opencv library and use `target_link_libraries(executable ${OpenCV_LIBS})` to link the opencv.

I switch on `SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)` so that I can see what are the commands for the compiler.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.3)
project (video_capture)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)

add_executable( vidcapture main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(vidcapture ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

As you can see from the compiler output ([link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69e5c617fe5febcc7c85)), the opencv libraries are linked twice after the `-ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt -lGLU -lGL -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext -ltbb`.
This seems creates issue when `-lrt` needs to be put at the end of the compiler commands as explained here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923495/undefined-reference-shm-open-already-add-lrt-flag-here)

It didn't work if I manually add the `-lrt` at the end of the compiler commands (i.e. `-lrt` appear twice, one before the opencv lib and one after).

Question:

1. Why the opencv is linked twice?
2. How should I overcome this issue so that `-lrt` is put at the end of the compiler commands only once?

UPDATE:

`MESSAGE("${OpenCV_LIBS}")` gives me:
opencv_videostab;**opencv_video**;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_photo;opencv_ocl;opencv_objdetect;opencv_nonfree;ope
 ncv_ml;opencv_legacy;opencv_imgproc;opencv_highgui;opencv_gpu;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_contrib;opencv_calib
 3d

while **the compiler commands** are:/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.9 */usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a* /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.9 -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt -lGLU -lGL -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext -ltbb /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.9 **/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.4.9** /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.9 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib

You can see that the opencv_video module is list before the opencv_ts module in the `${OpenCV_LIBS}` while in the compiler command it is put at afterwards.
I was wondering if this is some opencv self dependency issue (e.g. the opencv_video depends on the opencv_videostab which should be linked first?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that CMake has no shipped file `FindOpenCV.cmake`, so you use 3d party one for configure OpenCV library.

> 1. Why the opencv is linked twice?

Probably, `FindOpenCV.cmake` implementation is not perfectly correct.

> 2. How should I overcome this issue so that -lrt is put at the end of the compiler commands only once?

Just modify `OpenCV_LIBS` to one you want before linking to it:

```
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES OpenCV_LIBS) # duplicates are not needed anywhere
list(REMOVE_ITEM OpenCV_LIBS "-lrt") # remove "rt" library from the list..
list(APPEND OpenCV_LIBS "-lrt") # ..and insert it to the end
```

Comment: Can you please specify where should I put the three lists commands? I put it right after the `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )` which doesn't affect the compiler command. Thanks very much